# Does inclusion of continuous function into distribution has retraction?

Tags: distribution-theory

Sorry for I'm such a beginner of mathematics that there maybe something trival is missed. This looks terrible as a mixture of the language of analysis and the one of algebra. Whereas it appeals to me for the physical picture lying behind it.

---

My main problem is that, if we consider (all those distributions over $V$) $\mathcal D'(V)$ as a module over (all those compact support smooth / continuous functions over $V$) $\mathcal C(V)$ , we will have an exact sequence: $0 \rightarrow \mathcal C(V) \xrightarrow{i} \mathcal D' (V)$, where the inclusion defined as $i(f) := \int_V f\cdot(-) \mathrm d \mu$.

Therefore I'm wondering about whether the sequence has a retraction, or similarly, the exact sequence $\mathcal D' (V) \xrightarrow{p} \mathcal D' (V) / \mathcal C(V) \rightarrow 0$ is split or not.

So does the retraction $r$ which is continuous and a homomorphism of module exist? It is also acceptable if $r$ is simply a homomorphism of module.

---

This problem arised from the mathematical description of point charge $\delta$, we may consider it as a small ball, in order to ensure the electric potential is continuous. (but not the limit of testing function!) In this case, the retraction is the mapping sending $\delta$ into $1_{B(0, r)}$, the characteristic function over $B(0, r)$.

I dreamed that $r = (\alpha \mid 1_{B(x, r)})$, where $(\mid)$ is the pairing, is the solution. However sadly and evidently, this is not injective over $\mathcal C (V)$. Is there any possibility to adjust it into a retraction?